# Optimization by using lists instead of dicts in Python

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.2

I have some Python code that is far, far slower than it really ought to be.

```
#Generate planets
for t in range(stars*3): #There are 3 planets for every star, but not every star will have 3 planets
    theplanet=Planet()

    if random.randint(0,100) <= 25: #25% of planets have life
        theplanet.tl=random.randint(1,9)    #With a random tech level
    else:
        theplanet.tl=0  #The rest don't

    theplanet.star=stardict[random.choice(list(stardict.keys()))]     #Choose a random star
    theplanet.star.planets+=(theplanet,)    #Append the new planet to the star's list of planets
    theplanet.name=theplanet.star.name+"-"+str(len(theplanet.star.planets)) #Name the planet Starname-X, where X is the length of the star's planets tuple. Since this increases every time a planet is added, it will be 1 for the first planet, 2 for the next, etc...

    if math.floor((t/(stars*3))*100)==(t/(stars*3))*100: print("Generating planets: "+str((t/(stars*3))*100)+"% done.")
```

I'm pretty sure the bottleneck is in the `star=stardict[random.choice(list(` etc... line. I'm guessing here, but I assume dicts work by searching through every entry in the dict and seeing which one has the right key. Lists, I assume again, would just read off the information at a memory location derived from the entry number, and for extremely large (200,000 entries, to be exact) lists/dicts be much faster.

Would converting the dict's entries to a list make this code faster? How would I do this (I thought I saw a function for it, reviewing the docs now...)? Are there any other ways anyone notices to make this faster?

Comment: You're understanding of dictionary lookup doesn't appear to be correct.  dicts are hash tables -- so the lookup takes (on average) O(1) operations -- No search is needed.

Comment: You assume wrong. Dicts are based on hash tables which are just about the most efficient way to look things up.

Comment: @MarkRansom: While the OP is misinformed about dict lookup, putting it in a list would technically probably increase it even more. (It would get rid of the hashing step and any possibility of collision). The improvement is likely to be very marginal, though.

Comment: Ahhhh, I thought it might be a hash lookup, but then I wondered what you would do with all the memory space between the hash values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a list every time through the loop, but that list is unchanging. Move it outside of the loop.

```
starlist=list(stardict.keys())
...
    theplanet.star=stardict[random.choice(starlist)]     #Choose a random star
```

The problem almost certainly isn't in the dict lookup. They're based on hash tables which are quite fast.

Comment: ...and stardict.keys() is already a list, so you don't need the outer list()

Comment: @tdelaney No it isn't (the OP is using Python 3, in which it is a [view](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)).

Comment: @tdelaney, even if it is it doesn't hurt to force it, and I was just copying the original code.

Comment: @ katrielalex - I didn't notice that this is python 3. I may be a bit behind the times.

Comment: Should have caught that- though wouldn't it be even better to have starlist=list(stardict.values()) and skip the extra lookup? :P

Comment: @Schilcote, you're right - selecting from the values would be even better!

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the list generation `list(stardict.keys())` outside the loop
2. Try to profile your code ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html))
3. Assuming you are running CPython, check if your code could run with [Pypy](http://pypy.org/). This could lead to better performances due to its optimised JIT

Answer (score 0):

You only use the key as in intermediate value to select a random item in stardict. You can use the dictionary's value list directly instead:

```
#Generate planets
starlist = stardict.values()
for t in range(stars*3): #There are 3 planets for every star, but not every star will have 3 planets
    theplanet=Planet()

    if random.randint(0,100) <= 25: #25% of planets have life
        theplanet.tl=random.randint(1,9)    #With a random tech level
    else:
        theplanet.tl=0  #The rest don't

    theplanet.star=random.choice(starlist)     #Choose a random star
    theplanet.star.planets+=(theplanet,)    #Append the new planet to the star's list of planets
    theplanet.name=theplanet.star.name+"-"+str(len(theplanet.star.planets)) #Name the planet Starname-X, where X is the length of the star's planets tuple. Since this increases every time a planet is added, it will be 1 for the first planet, 2 for the next, etc...

    if math.floor((t/(stars*3))*100)==(t/(stars*3))*100: print("Generating planets: "+str((t/(stars*3))*100)+"% done.")
```